# Алгоритм Форда-Беллмана

Tags: c#, алгоритм

По курсовой нужна программная реализация этого алгоритма. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так? А то я никак не пойму, очень нужен взгляд со стороны. Вот что у меня получилось:

```
## Заголовок ## int n, s, m, k=0, mod_e=0; // k - счетчик массивов ребер
        int[] a = new int[200];         // массив начал ребер
        int[] b = new int[200];         // массив концов ребер
        int[] w = new int[200];         // массив весов ребер
        int[] d = new int[200];         // массив расстояний

        Console.WriteLine("Введите количество вершин:");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Количество вершин
        Console.WriteLine("Введите номер стартовой вершины:");
        s = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Стартовая вершина
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) // Задание массивов ребер
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите количество ребер, исходящих из вершины " +i);
                m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                    {
                        a[k] = i;
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите номер конечной вершины для "+ j + "-го ребра, исходящего из "+ i+ ":");
                        b[k] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите вес "+ j+ "-го ребра, исходящего из "+ i+ ":");
                        w[k] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        k++;
                    }
                mod_e++; // Кол-во ребер (во всем графе)
            }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) d[i] = 999999;
        d[s] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (i == s) i++;
                else
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j <= mod_e; j++)
                            {
                                if (d[b[j]] > (d[a[j]] + w[j])) d[b[j]] = d[a[j]] + w[j];
                                j++;
                            }
                        i++;
                    }
            }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Кратчайший путь до вершины " + i + " = " + d[i]); 
            }
        Console.WriteLine(d);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все заработало))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум, количество ребер во всем графе (mod_e) считается неправильно. По идее, оно должно равняться k (это одно и то же).
Плюс почему-то везде индексация в массивах начинается с 1, а не с 0 (хотя из-за этого вроде ошибок нет).